# How to search through every single table in database and remove specific rows

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq

I want to know how to search through multiple tables and remove specific rows.

For example:

- table_a has column issue_id
- table_b has column issue_id
- table_c has column issue_id

Consider the following LINQ / Entity Framework query:

```
Context db = new Context();

var row = from i in db.table_a
          where i.IssueID == 1
          select i;

db.Issues.RemoveRange(row);
```

This only deletes rows from table_a.  Is there any method that I can use to remove the similar rows from all three tables at the same time?

Comment: @STLDeveloper Thank you for edit my question and sorry if my question confuse you guys

Comment: Would you consider using an On Delete Cascade action in the DB schema design?

Comment: @Monza prefer linq but if can't then need to apply mysql

Comment: @SadLife - Have a look at: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach, in assumption that all interesting to us tables implement `Iissue_id` interface:

```
public interface Iissue_id
{
    int issue_id { get; set; }
}

public class table_a : Iissue_id
{
    public int issue_id { get; set; }
    //other properties
}

public void DeleteAllRowsWithIssue_id(int issue_id)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        foreach (var table in typeof(MyContext).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.GetInterface(nameof(Iissue_id)) != null).ToList())            
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"delete from {table.Name} where id = @p0", issue_id);
    }
}
```